# Converting number to number with two decimals

Tags: c#

Sorry if this question has already been asked I just can't find how to do it in my problem. 
I imported a file with a list of numbers from 1-20 into a listbox and then displayed the total amount of values and average into textboxes. I'm getting the right calculations it's just I have no clue how to convert them.

My code is:

```
int i = 0;
int result = 0;
while (i < lstbxDisplayInfo.Items.Count)
{
   result += Convert.ToInt32(lstbxDisplayInfo.Items[i++]);
}
//Displays average.
txtAverage.Text = Convert.ToString((double)result / i);
//Displays Amount.
txtAmount.Text = Convert.ToString((double) i);
```

my output is:

```
Average: 10.5
Total Amount: 20
```

I need the output to be:

```
Average: 10.50
Total Amount: 20.00
```

Comment: Have you try to format your results?

Comment: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need two decimal places i would use `decimal` instead. Two display them you can use `d.ToString("N2")`. Here is a more concise LINQ approach:

```
var allNums = lstbxDisplayInfo.Items.Cast<object>()
    .Select(o => decimal.Parse(o.ToString()));
decimal average = allNums.Average();
decimal total = allNums.Sum();
Console.WriteLine(average.ToString("N2"));
Console.WriteLine(total.ToString("N2"));
```

Comment: This helps a lot! I just changed the Console.WriteLine to txtAverage.Text and txtAmount to display in their textboxes.

Comment: But i Didn't mean the sum as total, sorry. I meant total numbers inputted into the listbox, what would I change Sum() to?

Comment: @user3041721: `Count` :)

Comment: ah thanks! I was trying to use length lol

Answer (score 6):

You can use `.ToString()` method with `#.00` format like;

```
(10.5).ToString("#.00");
(20).ToString("#.00");
```

Output will be;

```
10.50
20.00
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/11Sk1z)</kbd>.

- [`The "#" Custom Specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierD)

> The "#" custom format specifier serves as a digit-placeholder symbol.
>   If the value that is being formatted has a digit in the position where
>   the "#" symbol appears in the format string, that digit is copied to
>   the result string. Otherwise, nothing is stored in that position in
>   the result string.

**EDIT**: Of course `#` doesn't represents zeros, that's why you should use `#.00` instead of `#.##` format.

Comment: This converts `20.0` to `20` and not `20.00`.

Comment: @tahatmat Yeah, I figure out now. Thanks. Updated.